# How to read AssemblyInfo.cs into [SETUP]

Tags: inno-setup

I need to get AppVersion and VersionInfoVersion updated with what's in \Properties\Assemblyinfo.cs. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: There are preprocessor functions to read text files. Have you tried those? (Implicit in this question: Have you read the help?)

Comment: We have other binaries in other projects in the same solution. So I just went with doing a GetFileVersion on one of the other successful project builds. It seems quicker than parsing thru assemblyinfo.